# Screen goes blank after making a call since the Lollipop update

Tags: nexus-4, calls, screen, 5.0-lollipop

After I make or receive a call, the screen goes blank and becomes unresponsive. I have to restart the phone to use it again.  Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I don't think so. Has the update process went well?

Comment: Well, that looks like a bug ! I have been listening a lot over the forums that some users are complaining about the battery drain, some say that performance is decreased and all.... so you can consider it under bugs ! Better to keep your fingers for next bug fix update.

Comment: Please note that we are not a discussion forum, so I've removed the part asking if anyone has the issue.  (There appear to be *many* problems with Lollipop right now, especially on the N4.)  I'm afraid the answer might be "wait for an update".

Comment: Ditto. Same problem.

Comment: Same. This has been happening (and just happened) on my S4 GPe with 5.0. It makes my phone no longer a phone... Sometimes double-clicking my home button will get the task manager up, but often I need to reboot.